# WebServer: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-oauth, azure-web-app-service, google-api-dotnet-client

I feel that I'm doing something wrong...

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` is supposed to open a new browser window, and then user can authenticate himself...BUT! I'm using it on WebServer or even in WorkerRole in Azure cloud, so how technically `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` can open new browser window on client machine?

This is the second question that I ask, but now it is a more specific question, because I feel that I miss something. [The first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428026/authentication-for-google-api) has little bit more details on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am having issues properly understanding your problem, I am not exactly sure this is a problem it seams this is more a question about the inner workings of Googles .net client library and in that case may just be off topic for Stack but lets try this.

You have a web application, for authentication it just needs to show this browser window to the user

[image]

That is done by redirecting them to this window.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

Assuming they click accept the authentication is redirected to your webserver using the Redirect URI where you handle authentication.    Its not opening a new browser window on the users PC its redirecting there current page to the authentication then back to your webserver.

Again are you having a problem or is this just general curiosity as to how the client library works?

Comment: Thanks!! It not exactly answered my all questions, but now I understand that what I want is possible and I just doing something wrong....finally I found a missing peace...when I use gapi, I need to pass response_type: "code", instead of "token". Now on server I can exchange the code to access and refresh token and one of the posts on your web site helping me to implement it. Now I'm thinking how to create instance of UserCredential class, without calling GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync, because it looks like I do not need to use it, but maybe I miss something again :)

Comment: I have actually never tried mixing gapi and .net client.   I would love to hear if you get it working.

Comment: Yes, I got it working and everything looks perfect! I'm sending authorization code from client to server, server exchanges this code to access_token + refresh_token, then I create an instance of UserCredentials without using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync and then I can use google api. In order to get authorization code on client, response_type: "code" should be sent to gapi, and in order to get refresh_token on server, client should add "access_type": offline to gapi.

Comment: post your working code I am sure this will help others.